# Start Consul as windows service

Tags: windows, powershell, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I'm trying to run consul on windows, my steps:

1. Download consul.exe
2. Install nssm like

   2.1.`iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

   2.2.`choco install -y nssm`
3. Create config file for consul:

   `{
       "bootstrap": false,
       "server": true,
       "datacenter": "MyServices",
       "data_dir": "C:\Marchello\Downloads\cons\data",
       "log_level": "INFO"
   }`
4. Execute nssm command:

   `nssm install Consul C:\Marchello\Downloads\cons\consul.exe agent -config-dir C:\Marchello\Downloads\cons\config --ui-dir C:\Marchello\Downloads\cons\ui`
5. Got message `Service Consul installed successfully`
6. Run command `nssm start Consul`
   In result I'm getting message: `Consul: Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START control`

I'm confused, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RanadipDutta, i change the logon to admin and now service is started, thank u very much!

Comment: Happy to help. Posted as answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many of the services are starting actually? 
It happens when starting more than ~16 services. The first 16 will start successfully, and then the rest stays as in "Paused" state.

On the other hand, it might be a privilege issue. Changing the logon to Administrator should fix the issue.

Also, check Application event log for errors where the source is `nssm` around the time you have installed the service.

Hope the steps help you.

Answer (score 4):

Try using windows service sc.exe

> Basic Consul configuration JSON

```
{
  "datacenter": "east-aws",
  "data_dir": "d:\\workspace\\consul",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "node_name": "foobar",
  "server": true,
  "bind_addr": "127.0.0.1",
  "bootstrap": true,
  "ui": true,
  "log_file" : "d:\\workspace\\consul.log" 
}
```

Here above config.json is kept in this folder d:\workspace\consul

> sc.exe create "Consul" binPath= "d:\workspace\consul\Consul.exe agent -config-dir=d:\workspace\consul" start= auto

In the above command, a space is mandatory after binPath=**< space>** and also the open/close of the double quote. This means all the consul related command should come within the double quote.

> sc.exe start "Consul"